# why $scope.info binding late on ng-change in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolated-scope

**tag:**

```
<grid-filter varible="info.M_id" on-change="searchMember()">
</grid-filter>
```

**directive**

```
app.directive("gridFilter", function () {
return {      
scope: {
varible: "=",
onChange: "&"
},
template: [
'<div class="input-append input-group">',
'<input class="form-control border-right-0" ng-change="onChange();"   no-special-char  class="form-control" ng-model="varible"    />',
'<div class="input-group-append">',
' <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa-filter fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>',
' </div>',
' </div>'].join("")
};
})
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.searchMember = function () {      
    var data = $scope.info;
    Request.GetTabledata("SearchMemberData", data, null, $scope, true);
}
```

When typing on textbox for example `hello`. The controller doesn't bind `$scope.info.M_id` first time on change. Suppose that I  input `h` , `e` then `$scope.info.M_id` binds only `h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use one-way (`"<"`) binding for the input, and use the `on-change` event for output:

```
app.directive("gridFilter", function () {
    return {      
            scope: {
            varible: "<",
            onChange: "&"
        },
        template: `
          <div class="input-append input-group">
            <input class="form-control border-right-0"
                   ng-change="onChange({$event: varible})"
                   no-special-char  class="form-control" ng-model="varible"  />
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa-filter fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        `
    };
})
```

Usage:

```
<grid-filter  varible="info.M_id"
              on-change="info.M_id=$event; searchMember($event)">
</grid-filter>
```

```js
$scope.searchMember = function (data) {      
    console.log(data);
}
```

This will avoid the digest cycle delay inherent to two-way (`"="`) binding.

It has the added benefit of making future migration to Angular 2+ easier as Angular 2+ does not have two-way (`"="`) binding.

Comment: Yes it working..I am using on our project currently my task reduce work load on ui.. Thanx for helping